# Где должны быть запятые?

Tags: запятая

Оно – портал души и как сиять не забывало.

Answer (score 3):

После личных местоимений тире обычно не ставится. Но в данном предложении пауза выразительная, поэтому тире. 
КАК СИЯТЬ нужно обособить, так как это придаточное предложение, относящееся к слову  (НЕ)ЗАБЫВАЛО.
**Оно - портал души и, как сиять, не забывало.**

Comment: Спасибо!!!

Comment: Я бы слегка переделал вставную конструкцию : 

Оно - портал души,

И как **должно** сиять -

Не забывало!

(Душа **обязана** трудиться?)))

Comment: >behemothus, конечно, не ангел, но в данном случае я никакого хамства не заметила.  
  
А это обычное дело. Бегемота обидеть может всякий...
Писал уже, ну да простится мне самоцитирование...

Есть на свете очень милые скотики,  
Что не пьют, не глотают наркотики  
И живут безо всякой экзотики.  
А зовутся они бегемотики.  
  
Не такие уж они толстокожие,  
Не такие уж они глупорожие -  
Их всегда обижают прохожие,  
Потому что на них непохожие.  

Вот...

Да, DocentI, зайбите на математику. Там одна задачка, я бы от Вашей помощи не отказался.

Answer (score 1):

Оно – портал души и как сиять, не забывало. А можно так:Оно портал души и как сиять -  не забывало.

Answer (score 0):

(это не ответ. Комментарий к двум ответам сразу)

Ни в одном случае понятнее не стало. Фраза как нуждалась в переделке, так и нуждается.

Порта́л (англ. Portal — ворота, вход):

Портал (архитектура) — главный вход большого архитектурного сооружения...

Портал (техника) — металлическая несущая конструкция П-образной формы... 
` 
Портал (лекарство) — антидепрессант. Действующее вещество — флуоксетин...

Портал (фантастика) — разрыв в пространстве-времени...

Интернет-портал — крупный сайт, объединяющий различные сервисы...
....
(Вики)

В каком из этих значений "оно" будет ***сиять***?

Comment: Точно! Я так и не уверена, что поняла смысл предложения.

Comment: Сердце - портал души и, как сиять, не забывало. Это мистические стихи. Что тут странного? Обычное дело - сиять.)))

Comment: Что странного в мистических стихах?  Это - в мемориз.  
Но я не об этом. Опуская "философию", предлагаю сначала разобраться со смыслом фразы, - потом уже говорить о пунктуации. Давайте пошагово. Вы согласны в что в этой фразе вторая часть ("как сиять не уставало") никак не связано с первой?  
Если да, то что она модет представлять собой кроме риторического вороса ("И как это оно не уставало сиять?!")

Comment: "Вы согласны в что в этой фразе вторая часть никак не связано с первой?" - Нет, не согласна: душа - это Свет (сияет), если сердце - портал души, то и оно тоже сияет (как сиять, не забывало)

Comment: Тогда Вам не стоит интересоваться пунктуацией. 
Ставьте, где портал засияет -  не ошибетесь.

Comment: За участие спасибо, конечно! А зачем хамить-то???

Comment: Хамит всегда,

Хамит везде,

Где можно и не можно...

Хамит свинья - 

И будет при звезде,

У нас это возможно!

Comment: >А зачем хамить-то???  
  
За стихи - спасибо. Но зачем писать-то?  
Я Вас культурно спрашивал, какая связь между порталом и сияньем, а Вы мне предлагаете запятые расставлять исходя из мистического понимания? 
С этим -  к Дерзкому. Заобно и "за хамство" обсудите.

Comment: ЗЫ

Желудок, мой портал сияний,
Как ты хамить не забывало!
Среди свиней и дерзкой пьяни
Души заветное забрало!

Comment: Надо ввести постоянную рубрику и жечь глаголом сердца!

Comment: Вот и познакомились!)))))

Comment: Behemothus, конечно, не ангел, но в данном случае я никакого хамства не заметила.

Comment: Сиять  можно  в  первом  значении  -  вход.  Это  к  первому  комментарию  бегемотуса.